# My Fill-the-circles puzzles (Set #2)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

In each puzzle, fill the circles with the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... n, where n is the number of circles in such a way that consecutive numbers are NOT in circles that are joined with a line.

I designed all the puzzles in this set except the first one.  I don’t know where I found that particular puzzle.

[image: 8 circles #1]

[image: 8 circles #2]

[image: 8 circles #3]

[image: 9 circles]

[image: 10 circles]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the previous puzzles of this type, we can use a certain strategy to break into these puzzles logically:

> [image: puzzles with yellow circles]
>
>  Each of the yellow circles is connected to *every other circle in the puzzle but one*. So the yellow circles have to be the "endpoints" of the chain, and their non-neighbors are the numbers next to the endpoints:
>
>  [image: puzzles, each with circles filled in]
>
>  From here, it's easy to solve the puzzles:
>
>  [image: solved puzzles]

Comment: Good answer, except you made a mistake in my 2nd puzzle.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Fixed, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s still wrong.

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Fixed for real this time! (Counting from 1 to 8 is hard...)

Comment: Note that for n=8, after placing 1,2,7,8, the remaining empty cells match the problem n=4 from the set #1.  Likewise for n=9, after placing 1,2,8,9, the remaining white cells match the problem for n=5.