# My Fill-the-circles puzzles (Set #3)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

In each puzzle, fill the circles with the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... n, where n is the number of circles in such a way that consecutive numbers are NOT in circles that are joined by a line.

[image: 2 nested equilateral triangles]

[image: Regular pentagon with circle inside it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These both seem pretty straightforward to solve.

Solution for puzzle 1:

> [image: 1]

Solution for puzzle 2:

> [image: 2]

Comment: I agree that these two puzzles aren’t very tough.  You might want to check out my 2nd set of this type of puzzle, there a little bit more challenging.  You can find the 2nd set at:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/my-fill-the-circles-puzzles-set-2